# How to add a deadman's switch to an existing alert?

Tags: alert, influxdb, kapacitor

Say I have the following alert in tick.

```
stream
    |from()
        .measurement('cpu')
        .groupBy(*)
    |alert()
        .crit(lambda: "usage_idle" < 10)
        .topic('cpu')
```

I also want to be alerted if the cpu time series disappears. 
Can I add a `|deadman(...)` section after `|alert()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the `Deadman` node before.

Looking at the `Alert` documentation you should be able to call `Deadman` after it as `deadman` is a chaining method of `alert`.

**Quote:**

> AlertNode
>
> Chaining Methods
>
> - Alert
> - ...
> - Deadman

So the following should work;

```
 stream
    |from()
        .measurement('cpu')
        .groupBy(*)
    |alert()
        .crit(lambda: "usage_idle" < 10)
        .topic('cpu')
    |deadman(threshold, interval)
         ...
```

However if it doesn't you should be able to store the output of `stream` node into a variable and then apply it to both `alert` and `deadman` nodes separately.

**Example:**

```
 var data =  
   stream
     |from()
       .measurement('cpu')
       .groupBy(*)
data     
  |alert()
    .crit(lambda: "usage_idle" < 10)
    .topic('cpu')

data   
  |deadman(threshold, interval)
     ...
```

**References:**

AlertNode - https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.3/nodes/alert_node/#deadman

Comment: s/I have not use/I have not used/. Could you fix the typo. Since it is a single character change it does not allow me to edit it.

Comment: @HakanBaba Regexp performed. Thanks